# results group by month based on the datetime c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, there is a line chart in which I want to show record counts and the month on X-axis and Y-axis.

So I'm trying to call an ajax to the controller and the model has a record created date and the value.

I can't figure out how to return it by grouping it like the month of April has 15 records. The month of May has 12 records... likewise.

In my model structured like this,

```
 public class CustomerFeedBack {
   [Key]
   public int Id {
     get;
     set;
   }
   public DateTime CreatedDate {
     get;
     set;
   } = DateTime.Now;
   public int TotalSatisfaction {
     get;
     set;
   }
 }
```

This is the javascript of the chart, here in the `data` I want to return the count of records and for labels months. Currently, it has dummy data.

```
var bouData = {
    // Generate the days labels on the X axis.
    labels: Array.from(new Array(30), function (_, i) {
      return i === 0 ? 1 : i;
    }),
    datasets: [{
          label: 'Satisfied',
          fill: 'start',
          data: [1500, 800, 320, 180, 240, 320, 230, 650, 590, 1200, 750, 940, 1420, 1200, 960, 1450, 1820, 2800, 2102, 1920, 3920, 3202, 3140, 2800, 3200, 3200, 3400, 2910, 3100, 4250],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,123,255,0.1)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(0,123,255,1)',
          pointBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(0,123,255)',
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          pointRadius: 0,
          pointHoverRadius: 3
        },
```

So in the controller, I want to return JsonResult and bind to `labels` as month and `data` as count.

This is my incomplete controller code.

```
var satisfied = (from a in db.tbl_Main where a.TotalSatisfaction >= 12 
                 select new {
                  // Here I want to check with the create date group it as Month and sum the value of a.TotalSatisfaction count.
                 }).ToList();
```

I'm not an experienced developer regarding this, Still learning and would appreciate if you can suggest if there is another way of doing this easily or how to complete this.

Thanks.

Updating the question May 19, 2022

I have applied this code within the jasonresult

```
var satisfied = db.tbl_Main.Where(m => m.TotalSatisfaction >= 12).GroupBy(
                            m => new { m.CreatedDate.Year, m.CreatedDate.Month },
                            m => m.TotalSatisfaction
                            ).ToList();
```

It's shows like this

[image]

It shows the count `4` which means for the Month of `05` it has 4 records.

I printed the results in the console and it shows as

[image]

Here I want to know, I want to show these months and the counts in the line chart. So I hope, If I could return the data like `Month` `count` I will be able to show it on the chart right? or any ideas from the experience?

This below script is I'm returning the values, so hoping to show in the labels `month` and the data section `count`.

```
var bouData = {
            // Generate the days labels on the X axis.
            labels: Array.from(new Array(30), function (_, i) {
                return i === 0 ? 1 : i;
            }),
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Satisfied',
                fill: 'start',
                data: [1500, 800, 320, 180, 240, 320, 230, 650, 590, 1200, 750, 940, 1420, 1200, 960, 1450, 1820, 2800, 2102, 1920, 3920, 3202, 3140, 2800, 3200, 3200, 3400, 2910, 3100, 4250],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,123,255,0.1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(0,123,255,1)',
                pointBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(0,123,255)',
                borderWidth: 1.5,
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHoverRadius: 3
            },
```

Comment: I didn't get the part where you say you want months on the X and the JavaScript says days on the X?

Comment: @CaiusJard now currently records are saved according to the DateTime. So from that, I want to extract and group the same month data and the records of >=12 count

Comment: Yes, but the JavaScript creates 30 labels "for days" and you said you want a bunch of data that is "months" - I'm assuming you want months but if you want to analyse the satisfaction per day regardless the yearmonth  month (ie add up all the satisfactions on every 1st day of any yearmonth) it's slightly different

Answer (score 0):

This should be translatable to SQL by whatever ORM you're using:

```
var satisfied = db.tbl_Main
    .Where(m => m.TotalSatisfaction >= 12)
    .GroupBy(
      m => new { m.CreatedDate.Year, m.CreatedDate.Month },
      m => m.TotalSatisfaction
    )
    .Select(g => new {
       label = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1),
       data = g.Sum()
    })
    .ToList();
```

but do say if it doesn't..

We group by a key of the year and month, and emit only the TotalSatisfaction from the group. Later we'll sum this up per yearmonth giving a list of distinct yearmonths and the total of their satisfactions

Comment: Hi Caius. Thanks for the answer, these days I have tried using this in my solution but it didn't work as I wanted.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: Hi! I have updated the question. The section starts at ``Updating the question May 19, 2022``. Please can you check?

Comment: Change the `g.Sum()` in my code to `g.Count()` instead. Note that you do not appear to have transported my suggestion in the Select, into your code at all; you'll need to (or you'll need to use the overload of GroupBy that does it)

Comment: I have tried your answer but there is an error. So I have to remove the ``select`` section to figure out where the error occurs.

Comment: is something missing in this part ?? ``label = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1)`` there is an error shows after the ``)`` closing brackets and I tried ``,`` didn't worked.

Comment: Error is ``Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities``

Comment: There was a missing `,` on the end of the `label = ` line but that should cause *Syntax error ',' expected* not, the error you say you're getting, Edit the full exact code that causes the *Only parameterless ..* error into the question